# AS3 #1063: var count mismatch onSym01() expected 0, got 1

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to add a symbol to stage but I'm getting argument error.

My code:

```
symHolder.mc.sym01_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragHandler);

function startDragHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("Sym" + event.target.name.charAt(3) + event.target.name.charAt(4)) as Class;
    var s:MovieClip = (new ClassReference("s" + num) as MovieClip);
    s.x = mouseX;
    s.y = mouseY;
    toggleSymHolder(null);
    addChild(s);
    s.name = "s" + num;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragHandler);
    s.startDrag();
    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, nextDrag);
    num ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the class contructor take any params? If not remove the `"s"+num` from the constructor.

```
(new ClassReference("s" + num) as MovieClip);
```

should be :

```
(new ClassReference() as MovieClip);
```